# Easier Cross-Browser CSS3 Features

Tags: html, css

To add box-shadow to a HTML element, I currently have to do this:

`box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #969696;

-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #969696;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #969696; 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#969696', Direction=145, Strength=3);`

At this point, it seems to me that this amount of code for a simple gradient is ridiculous at this stage of the web. Not to mention the maintenance time- if I want to change the color, I have to change it four times for each vendor prefix. (This also applies for things like CSS3 Gradients).

What's a better, more optimized way for handling this simply? I'm aware there are large non-standard fixes like [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/), but in my experience, they take forever to load and I still have to write code for Firefox & Webkit. Do I need to resort to server-side code to do this? I'm just really frustrated working with redundant awkward-looking code.

Comment: Internet explorer should die.

Comment: @Luke: Couldn't agree more. You'd think a multi-billion dollar company could come up with a browser that supports even basic CSS3 features... but apparently that's too complicated for Microsoft. :)

Comment: The fact that they let their browser read `<!--If IE` tags makes me think standard is not what they're going for. D=<

Comment: Use only `box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #969696;` which is likely the one that will end up in the standard, and some browser already support it and the page will look fine. Browsers that don't support it yet will have a less appealing looking page, which in turn might convince the user to switch to a more advanced Browser. It's the most sane approach from the programmer's point of view, I wonder whether your client will agree with this though. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use any of the following to ease your sorrows:

**Dynamic Stylesheet Languages/CSS Extensions**

- [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)
- [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)
- [Compass (Sass Framework)](http://compass-style.org/)

**CSS 3 Generators**

- [Prefixr](http://prefixr.com/)
- [CSS 3 Please](http://css3please.com/)
- [CSS 3 Generator](http://css3generator.com/)
- [Mother Effing HSL](http://mothereffinghsl.com/)
- [Mother Effing Text Shadow](http://mothereffingtextshadow.com/)
- [CSS 3 Maker](http://www.css3maker.com/)
- [CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)
- [CSS Filter Effects](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html)

Comment: +1 for sass, better then the other pre processors I have seen before. You should also add compass to this

Comment: you might also add http://enjoycss.com :) probably the best one

Comment: @Nedudi - Added! Awesome find!

Answer (score 1):

[cssSandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use Less CSS framework with bootstrap's preboot here http://markdotto.com/bootstrap/